# using categories for some classes and not for the full code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, objective-c-category

I have a category for my `UINavigationBar`. I want to use that category for customizing my navigation bar but not for the every navigation bar in that project. How can I do that.

Comment: Simply don't invoke the category methods where you don't want them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define that category in that class file(.m) itself, instead of a separate file.

Comment: That link has it's terminology wrong. When you declare an anonymous category it's called a [class extension](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html).

Comment: ooops... so i am removing that link.

Comment: Not entirely the OP would need to be using a custom subclass of `UINavigationBar`, which it does not sounds like they are doing if they are just adding a category to `UINavigationBar`

Comment: I want the drawRect method of navigationBar to override for a class say 'A.h' and 'A.m' using a navigationBar

Comment: So, for overriding you must not use category, you should subclass it.